# Sharepoint Files Connect identifiers in Content Version Object

Tags: lightning-web-components, contentversion, content, sharepoint

After uploading a Sharepoint file via Salesforce **Files Connect**, i see a record gets created in **Content Version object**

I want to know one of the field in Content Version (ExternalDocumentInfo2) , how it is populated

For eX -

```
item:L3NpdGVzL1NpZEZpcnN0U2l0ZQ:69f4b76f-3d61-4fad-bdf8-d10c1101c42d:5ec14c97-a7ea-4a39-8b1e-88a2411adf76:4
```

after lots of debugging i found out

```
   - L3NpdGVzL1NpZEZpcnN0U2l0ZQ - Root path which is encoded
   - 69f4b76f-3d61-4fad-bdf8-d10c1101c42d - What is this. I am unable to make it out.
   - 5ec14c97-a7ea-4a39-8b1e-88a2411adf76 - Document Folder ID
   - 4 - Item ID
```

I want to know what is the 2nd part in the string

> 69f4b76f-3d61-4fad-bdf8-d10c1101c42d

Comment: does anyone have any idea what the 2nd part of the string is in Sharepoint?

Comment: did you get the answer? i am also stuck on same thing

Comment: Can you give me pointers on how to upload a file to SharePoint using files connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part is the webId, which is the unique identifier (guid) for the item's site (SPWeb). https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepointids?view=graph-rest-1.0